# Failing Review Audit because I added a comment that it was a duplicate post

Tags: support, review-audits

I originally posted this to Meta Stack Exchange and was told that it should be here instead.

I reviewed a post in the Super User First Post queue and thought it sounded familiar. I searched for the subject and found a previous post with the same question. I then added a comment recommending they search for previous questions and gave them a link to the duplicate question and answers. Since the audit changed the name of the user, there was no way for me to know otherwise. So why would I fail then?

[image: Failed Audit picture]

Comment: Was this in the Very Low Quality posts queue?

Comment: No, it was in the First Posts queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I then added a comment recommending they search for previous questions and gave them a link to the duplicate question and answers.

You should have flagged as a duplicate instead of commenting they should search for something.

> Since the audit changed the name of the user, there was no way for me to know otherwise.

You could have clicked to view the actual question, but in general the name of the user was changed, so you wouldn’t be biased about whom they were.

> So why would I fail then?

There was nothing wrong with the question, so doing nothing, was the correct course of action.  You failed the audit for that reason.

It’s a single failure, learn from the mistake, and don’t repeat the same mistake and you will be fine.